# ActionBar is always shown with Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-fullscreen

I am implementing an app. I want the first screen does not show the `ActionBar`, but it is always shown. I can not hide it. It is also not shown in `Fullscreen`. This is my code:

**MANIFEST**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.LoginMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**STYLES**

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

**LOGINMAIN**

```
public class LoginMain extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
}
```

Comment: @MD You have not understood me. I would not be displayed but it shows

Comment: change style name to anything and there should be parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"

Comment: @Harry Style Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen should not extend itself

Comment: You didn't get it, ok, delete your style itselft as it has conflicting name

Answer (score 0):

If you want hide your title put this in your onCreate mehod:

```
public class LoginMain extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put the below code snippet in the AndroidManifest file of your application under the "application" section.

```
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

The Title bar will be disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In Your `styles.xml` file add this

```
<style name="myOwnTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

And in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file under `<activity>` add this if you your activity had not implemented any `Theme` before.

```
android:theme="@style/myOwnTheme"
```

And if your activity had already any `Theme` replace it.

**OR**
In you `.java` class `onCreate()` method add this

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

**Note:** Use this in `onCreate()` above `**setContentView**`

Answer (score 0):

Try for this one

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"  parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```